# Is MOM systems a Space Base Architecture?

Tags: architecture, jms, mom

Is `Message Oriented Middleware` (such as `JMS` in `JEE`) a `Space Base Architecture`?
If answer is false so what is different between a `MOM` systems and a `Space` base systems?

Answer (score 2):

MOM is a message relay technology only. SBA is a grid computing pattern to scale data processing.

MOM technology never deals with data processing, just distribution of messages.

However, MOM technology can be used to distribute messages around to processing units - achieving linear scalability of processing power by load balancing messages. SBAs on the other side tend to lean on a distributed memory/grid rather than message passing.

To make things more academic, some MOM are implemented on top of distributed memory systems.

So - you are comparing apples to berry bushes. Not really the same thing.